# RewriteRule "P" flag results in server 500 error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` file to modify an incoming URL. It works fine except I want the rule to act as a proxy, rather than a redirect. But if I append the `[P]` proxy flag to the rule then the rule triggers a 500 error. The Apache logs show a 500 log when the rewrite rule includes the "P" flag and a normal 302 log for the same URL when the rule does not include the "P" flag. Note that the result is the same for any valid URL pattern and URL substitution specified in the rewrite rule.

I enabled `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` by entering `sudo a2enmod proxy` and `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` followed by `sudo systemctl restart apache2` but I'm still getting the 500 error. When I enter `apachectl -M` the following two lines appear in the list:

```
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
```

Does anyone know what else is needed to get RewriteRule's proxy flag to work?

Comment: What is the relevant configuration? What is in the error log?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - The Apache logs show a 500 log when the rewrite rule includes the "P" flag and a normal 302 log for the same URL when the rule does not include the "P" flag. I'm not sure what configuration you're referring to, but I did not include the syntax of rewrite rule since the result is the same for any valid rule URL pattern and rule URL substitute.

Comment: First, you should show an actual RewriteRule. Second, you should check the error log.

Comment: The 500 server _response_ (that appears in the server's "access log") is just a generic "catch all" HTTP response for when the server is unable to handle the request (there was an "Internal Server Error" of some kind). The server's "error log" should contain the specific details of this "server error".

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton and MrWhite, the error logs did indeed provide the answer (SSLProxyEngine needed to be enabled). It is the first time I've had to look at the Apache logs in a few years and had forgotten the errors are in separate files. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

SSLProxyEngine needs to be set to "on" in the site's Apache conf file.

Answer (score -3):

I have get same issue.
Fixed by add the following code to Apache conf file:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```

Comment: This has already been posted, there is no need to add the same answer again. After earning some reputation you can upvote helpful answers.